How can I parse the SPARK SQL by calcite SqlParser? Like Create Temporary table
I want to parse the SPARK SQL by calcite.
Here is the keywords and related usage in spark sql: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-ansi-compliance.html#sql-keywords-optional-disabled-by-default
I have two questions:

How to parse the SPARK SQL by calcite?
How can I extend the syntax on demand? like create temporary table?

For question1:
Here is the example code to parse spark sql:
Config config = SqlParser.config()
//        .withLex(Lex.MYSQL)
//        .withConformance(SqlConformanceEnum.BABEL)
        .withParserFactory(SqlDdlParserImpl.FACTORY);

SqlParser sqlParser = SqlParser.create("create temporary table test1 as select * from test",config);
SqlNode sqlNode = sqlParser.parseQuery();

But it failed with below error:
Caused by: org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.ddl.ParseException: Encountered "temporary" at line 1, column 8.
Was expecting one of:
    "FOREIGN" ...
    "OR" ...
    "MATERIALIZED" ...
    "SCHEMA" ...
    "TABLE" ...
    "TYPE" ...
    "VIEW" ...
    "FUNCTION" ...
    
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.ddl.SqlDdlParserImpl.generateParseException(SqlDdlParserImpl.java:45760)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.ddl.SqlDdlParserImpl.jj_consume_token(SqlDdlParserImpl.java:45571)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.ddl.SqlDdlParserImpl.SqlCreate(SqlDdlParserImpl.java:22975)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.ddl.SqlDdlParserImpl.SqlStmt(SqlDdlParserImpl.java:3653)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.ddl.SqlDdlParserImpl.SqlStmtEof(SqlDdlParserImpl.java:4194)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.ddl.SqlDdlParserImpl.parseSqlStmtEof(SqlDdlParserImpl.java:213)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseQuery(SqlParser.java:172)
    ... 28 more

I also tried the Lex.MYSQL and it supports the temporary. But there are so many keywords and usages  in spark sql that are different from MYSQL. Is there any way to parse the spark sql with the parser that support the spark sql?
For question2:
I tried to extend the syntax with below steps but met the strange compile error with the copied Parser.jj file.
Steps

Copy the Parser.jj file from calcite
add SqlNode SqlCreateTempTable() :... in parserImpls.ftl
add class CreateTempTable that extends SqlCall to define the getOperator, getOperandList, unparse
add related config in config.fmpp
mvn generate-sources to generate the TestSqlParserImpl that defined in the step 4

at step5, it has below error:
FMPP processing session failed.
[ERROR] Caused by: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
[ERROR] ==> default  [in template "Parser.jj" at line 1124, column 43]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] ----
[ERROR] Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
[ERROR] ----
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] ----
[ERROR] FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
[ERROR]         - Failed at: #if (parser.createStatementParserMeth...  [in template "Parser.jj" at line 1124, column 1]

Is my steps right? And why the same Parser.jj file has error when compile?

There are three SQL parsers provided out of the box by the Apache Calcite project:

SqlParserImpl (for SQL; mostly conforming to SQL standard)
SqlBabelParserImpl (for DDL, DML, SQL; supports multiple DB specific variants)
SqlDdlParserImpl (for DDL, supports some of the most commonly used statements)

The most liberal one is the Babel parser so your best bet for parsing Apache Spark SQL would be to use the respective factory and start from there.
The CREATE TEMPORARY syntax is not supported by any parser at the moment. Nevertheless, the Babel parser supports CREATE VOLATILE syntax so it should be rather straightforward to add support for TEMPORARY as well.
For adding your own parser extensions as a separate project you will need to use some Maven/Gradle plugins such as:

maven-dependency-plugin
fmpp-maven-plugin
javacc-maven-plugin

There are various opensource projects that have done this in the past so you can take some inspiration from there. If you have a maven build you can look at how Apache Drill does it by checking the respective pom.xml file and directory structure.

Maybe you cannot do that, I didn't find spark_sql in SqlConformanceEnum
